# SQL: get all column records with same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, row

I'm quite new to sql and I'm having trouble writing this
i have a table like this

```
id   name
1   A
2   B
3   C
1   D
1   E
1   F
...
```

I  want a query that will return to me the names of the ID i give it... say if i ask for 1, i want it to return A D E F
i tried  this in PHP:

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id='1'", $link);

    $pfilearray=array();
    $pfilearray=mysql_fetch_assoc($result3);

    print_r($pfilearray);
```

but this gives me only the first name found with id 1, what am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should iterate the whole result set using while() and mysql_fetch_assoc(). example:

```
while(($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))!=null)
{
    $pfilearray[]=$rs['name'];
}
print_r($pfilearray);
```

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://uk.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) returns one row from your result set so it will only return the first value. You need to loop through your result set ($result3 in your code) and get all the rows.

btw, the mysql_ family of functions is quite old and most people would suggest using the mysqli_ family, or even better, [PDO](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

EDIT:
A very basic PDO example:

```
$ddh = new PDO( /* connection details */ );
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM table WHERE id= ? ');
$sth->execute(array(1));
$names = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: i don't mind using `fetch_assoc` is there another command?  
also how do i loop though? with `foreach`?  
will look into the pdo you suggest, thanx

Comment: @krasatos I have added a basic PDO example. I would suggest reading the docs and then searching SO, the web for some tutorials...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code and verify you could able to retieve

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{
  echo $row['name'];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your result set using mysql_fetch_array().
For more help [click here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id='1'", $link);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{
  echo $row['name'];
}
```